# Why Solid Insulators have highest breakdown voltage?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, insulators

Why does solid insulating materials have a higher breakdown voltage when compared to that of liquids and gases? Can anyone explain this in simple words?

Answer (score 3):

In general solids can store more energy in their electric fields due to their polarization mechanisms.

"Permittivity (denoted by ε; measured in farads/meter, F/m) is the property that permits a substance to store energy in, and release energy from, an electric field.   This property allows a substance to buffer any change in the applied electric field. The higher the permittivity of the medium, the more energy is absorbed by the medium resulting in greater attenuation of the applied electric field.  The physical basis of permittivity is polarization, the process by which bound charges (charges that cannot produce current) rearrange themselves in a manner that will oppose any externally applied electric field.  Highly polarizable materials (dielectrics) have a high ε value."

Some interesting data -
From

http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/elmat_en/kap_3/backbone/r3_2_1.html

[image]